# How to non-destructively check if an HTTP client has shut down the connection?

Tags: http, go, server

I have a `net/http` Server serving a GET request (via `ServeHTTP()`) which can take a very long time to complete. Consequently, no client timeout is configured server side. However, the connected client may have shut down its connection to the server (typically due to a timeout on its side, but of course, other reasons are possible as well). I have no control over the clients.

How do I detect such a condition within `ServeHTTP()` without "disturbing" the connection?

- I cannot send a series of `1xx` response headers because it's not supported by `ResponseWriter.WriteHeader()` (also, it allows only one header to be set and does not return anything).
- I cannot use `ResponseWriter.Write()` with zero-sized data, as that would send a header.

What other options do I have?

Edit: this is not a duplicate of [how to close/abort a Golang http.Client POST prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197685/how-to-close-abort-a-golang-http-client-post-prematurely) because there the question is how to cancel a request from the client side while my question is about detecting such a cancellation from the server side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to close/abort a Golang http.Client POST prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197685/how-to-close-abort-a-golang-http-client-post-prematurely)

Comment: Much clearer. Thanks.  It's still a duplicate, though :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interrogate the [request context](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Context):

> For incoming server requests, the context is canceled when the client's connection closes, the request is canceled (with HTTP/2), or when the ServeHTTP method returns.

```
var r *http.Request
select {
    case <-r.Context().Done():
        // Client gave up
    default:
}
```