# Implement the io.Reader interface to cancel the form upload on the client side

Tags: http, go, client

I've used time.Sleep(n) before to accomplish client-side manual cancellation of uploads, but the value of n is not well determined and this approach is not very elegant. I now want to manually call cancel() by implementing the io.Reader interface.
Below is the client code

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "io"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
)

type CancelReader struct {
    cancel func()
    offset int32
    size   int32
    flag   bool
    stop   int32
}

func (c CancelReader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if c.flag {
        return 0, nil
    }
    log.Printf("Read n %d size %d stop %d offset %d \n", n, c.size, c.stop, c.offset)
    c.flag = true

    if c.offset >= c.size {
        return 0, io.EOF
    }
    n = len(p)
    log.Println("N :", n)
    str := "0123456789abcdefg"
    b := []byte(str)
    var res []byte
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().Unix()))
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        res = append(res, b[r.Intn(len(b))])
    }
    n = copy(p, res)
    c.offset += int32(n)
    if c.offset >= c.stop {
        c.cancel()
    }
    c.flag = false
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)
    return n, nil
}

const (
    filename  = "/Users/jimyag/Downloads/aDrive.dmg"
    targetUrl = "http://localhost:9999/upload"
)

func main() {
    bodyBuf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    bodyWriter := multipart.NewWriter(bodyBuf)
    
    fileWriter, err := bodyWriter.CreateFormFile("uploadfile", filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error writing to buffer")
    }
    
    fh, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error opening file")
    }
    defer fh.Close()
    _, err = io.Copy(fileWriter, fh)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }

    contentType := bodyWriter.FormDataContentType()
    bodyWriter.Close()

    cx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    cancelReader := CancelReader{
        cancel: cancel,
        offset: 0,
        size:   1024 * 256,
        flag:   false,
        stop:   1024 * 50,
    }
    req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, targetUrl, cancelReader)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", contentType)
    req = req.WithContext(cx)
    _, err = http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    log.Println(err)

}
```

server

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/upload", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        file, _, err := request.FormFile("uploadfile")
        if err != nil {
            if request.Context().Err() != nil {
                log.Printf("context err %+v", request.Context().Err())
            }
            log.Printf("err %+v", err)
            return
        }
        p := make([]byte, 10)
        defer file.Close()
        size := 0
        for {
            n, err := file.Read(p)
            if err != nil {
                if errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
                    log.Printf("read end")
                } else {
                    log.Printf("read unknow err %+v", err)
                }
                break
            }
            size += n

        }
        log.Printf("read end size %d \n", size)
    })
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9999", nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf(err.Error())
    }

}
```

[running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69NKs.png)

[how to close/abort a Golang http.Client POST prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197685/how-to-close-abort-a-golang-http-client-post-prematurely)

Comment: why not try `context.WithTimeout` it will automatically cancel the request after the timeout? make sure the timeout is smaller so that the cancellation happens before the upload tasks complete

Comment: In the process of implementing Read(), I did not use the method of the pointer receiver of the structure, and the third parameter body io.Reader of http.NewRequest() did not pass the pointer. The program just compiles and passes, but when running During the process, the structure cannot modify the value in the offset, so the value of the offset is always 0. Now just change the Read to the method with a pointer receiver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stdlib `testing` package has a little-known gem: `iotest`.

In particular, [HalfReader](https://pkg.go.dev/testing/iotest@go1.18.3#HalfReader) might be what you need (or you could take HalfReader and modify it to stop at a different point.