# Stop all running nested loops inside for -> go func -> for loop

Tags: go

The best way I figured out how to "multi-thread" requests with a different proxy each time was to nest a go func and for loop inside of another for loop, but I can't figure out how to stop all loops like a break normally would, I tried a regular break also tried break out and added out: above the loops but that didn't stop it.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest"
)

func main(){
    rep := 100 
    for i := 0; i < rep; i++ { 
        log.Println("starting loop")
        go func() { 
            for{
                request := gorequest.New()
                resp, body, errs := request.Get("https://discord.com/api/v9/invites/family").End()
                if errs != nil {
                    return
                }
                if resp.StatusCode == 200{
                    var result map[string]interface{}
                    json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &result)
                    serverName := result["guild"].(map[string]interface{})["name"]       
                    log.Println(sererName +" response 200, closing all loops")

                    //break all loops and goroutine here
                }
            }
        }
    }
    log.Println("response 200,closed all loops")
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code.

Comment: Added the image since I couldn't get it to format correctly, got it now though

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6807590/11810946) or [the tour](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/5) help? There is no way to [directly stop a goroutine](https://go.dev/doc/faq#no_goroutine_id); you need to provide a signal (generally via a channel) that the goroutine checks.

Comment: Can you include more context around your application specific problem? It's unclear to me what the problem actually is based on the example code and description.

Comment: I've added more code for context

Comment: Why is the goroutine in the loop necessary? Is there a reason you can't just loop until the request succeeds if that's what you're trying to do?

Comment: Doing regular loops with proxies takes quite some time if the response isnt 200, I was trying to do as many requests as possible with a different proxy until it got a 200

Comment: You would need to add a way to cancel an in-progress call to `request.Get`. Taking a guess at what `request.Get` is doing I'd suggest you look at [`http.NewRequestWithContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#NewRequestWithContext) (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29197685/11810946)). A [context](https://pkg.go.dev/context) is one way to pass a signal telling a long running operation to stop. If you edit your example so its self-contained (i.e. it compiles) then someone will be able to show you how that works.

Comment: sure ill edit it

Answer (score 2):

Answering this would be complicated by your use of `parnurzeal/gorequest` because that package does not provide any obvious way to cancel requests (see [this issue](https://github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest/issues/255)). Because your focus appears to be on the process rather than the specific function I've just used the standard library (`http`) instead (if you do need to use `gorequest` then perhaps ask a question specifically about that).

Anyway the below solution demonstrates a few things:

- Uses a [Waitgroup](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup) so it knows when all go routines are done (not essential here but often you want to know you have shutdown cleanly)
- Passes the result out via a channel (updating shared variables from a goroutine leads to [data races](https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector)).
- Uses a [context](https://pkg.go.dev/context) for cancellation. The `cancel` function is called when we have a result and this will stop in progress requests.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    // Get the context and a function to cancel it
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel() // Not really required here but its good practice to ensure context is cancelled eventually.

    results := make(chan string)

    const goRoutineCount = 100
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(goRoutineCount) // we will be waiting on 100 goRoutines

    for i := 0; i < goRoutineCount; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done() // Decrement WaitGroup when goRoutine exits

            req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, "https://discord.com/api/v9/invites/family", nil)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
            if err != nil {
                if errors.Is(err, context.Canceled) {
                    return // The error is due to the context being cancelled so just shutdown
                }
                panic(err)
            }
            defer resp.Body.Close() // Ensure body is closed
            if resp.StatusCode == 200 {
                var result map[string]interface{}
                if err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&result); err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
                serverName := result["guild"].(map[string]interface{})["name"]
                results <- serverName.(string) // Should error check this...
                cancel()                       // We have a result so all goroutines can stop now!
            }
        }()
    }

    // We need to process results until everything has shutdown; simple approach is to just close the channel when done
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(results)
    }()

    var firstResult string
    requestsProcessed := 0
    for x := range results {
        fmt.Println("got result")
        if requestsProcessed == 0 {
            firstResult = x
        }
        requestsProcessed++ // Possible that we will get more than one result (remember that requests are running in parallel)
    }

    // At this point all goroutines have shutdown
    if requestsProcessed == 0 {
        log.Println("No results received")
    } else {
        log.Printf("xx%s response 200, closing all loops (requests processed: %d)", firstResult, requestsProcessed)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great thank you, could you do 1 more thing and show how to use a proxy with the standard request library please

Comment: That would be a different question that has [been answered previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14661511/11810946). If you have a specific question on this (not answered in the link) then you are probably better to ask it separately (I have not had to use a proxy with Go).